# How do I limit the border size on a matplotlib graph?

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, plot

I'm making some pretty big graphs, and the whitespace in the border is taking up a lot of pixels that would be better used by data. It seems that the border grows as the graph grows.

Here are the guts of my graphing code:

```
        import matplotlib
        from pylab import figure

        fig = figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot_date((dates, dates), (highs, lows), '-', color='black')
        ax.plot_date(dates, closes, '-', marker='_', color='black')

        ax.set_title('Title')
        ax.grid(True)
        fig.set_figheight(96)
        fig.set_figwidth(24)
```

Is there a way to reduce the size of the border? Maybe a setting somewhere that would allow me to keep the border at a constant 2 inches or so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it looks like you're just using a single subplot, you may want to skip `add_subplot` and go straight to [`add_axes`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes).  This will allow you to give the size of the axes (in figure-relative coordinates), so you can make it as large as you want within the figure.  In your case, this would mean your code would look something like

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    fig = plt.figure()

    # add_axes takes [left, bottom, width, height]
    border_width = 0.05
    ax_size = [0+border_width, 0+border_width, 
               1-2*border_width, 1-2*border-width]
    ax = fig.add_axes(ax_size)
    ax.plot_date((dates, dates), (highs, lows), '-', color='black')
    ax.plot_date(dates, closes, '-', marker='_', color='black')

    ax.set_title('Title')
    ax.grid(True)
    fig.set_figheight(96)
    fig.set_figwidth(24)
```

If you wanted, you could even put the parameters to `set_figheight`/`set_figwidth` directly in the `figure()` call.

Answer (score 6):

Try the [`subplots_adjust`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust) API:

> subplots_adjust(*args, **kwargs)
>
> fig.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, wspace=None, hspace=None)
>
> Update the SubplotParams with kwargs (defaulting to rc where None) and update the subplot locations

Comment: Can you provide na example of how you'd use it in this case?